# how to use linked list to read in txt file in c++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

this is what i have so far but this will not read in an undetermined length of the text file

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>   
#include <fstream>  

using namespace std ;

int main() 
    {

char *file_name = "doc.txt" ; 

ifstream fin ;
fin.open( file_name ) ;

if( ! fin ) {
    cout << "Problems opening " << file_name << endl ;
    return -1 ;
}


const unsigned MAX = 100 ; 
string doc[MAX] ;

unsigned word_count = 0 ;


while( fin >> doc[ word_count ] ) 

{
    cout << doc[ word_count ] << endl ;
    word_count ++ ;
}


fin.close() ;

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure where the linked list is here?

Comment: He wants to use linked list to read in the words, but, doesn't know how to. I think.

Comment: what are the errors you're getting? is the problem the undetermined length of the file, or a line within a text file? Consider reformatting your code with fewer blank lines to make it easier to read.

Comment: yes i will eventually get a segmentation fault after it passes the length of array i have allocated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) and push your new words onto it.

[stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/) would be faster if you're just pushing and popping.

Or, there's always [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/).

Really depends a lot on what you're doing, and if speed matters.

Comment: Perhaps another container would be even better, but `std::vector` is certainly an improvement over a C-style array.